# How to overcome fixedpoint division problem in chisel3?

Tags: arithmetic-expressions, chisel, fixed-point, chiseltest

When I am running a code for testing in fixedpoint, I am getting an error. Can anyone help me with the code???
Code:

```scala
    import chisel3._
    import chisel3.util._
    import chisel3.experimental.FixedPoint
    import chisel3.internal.ChiselException

    import scala.language.experimental.macros

    class FPMul extends Module {
        val io = IO(new Bundle {
            val a = Input(FixedPoint(4.W, 2.BP))
            val b = Input(FixedPoint(4.W, 2.BP))
            val p = Output(FixedPoint(8.W, 2.BP))
        })

        io.p := io.a + io.b / 6.0.F(0.BP)
    }
```

Error:

```
#### chisel3.internal.ChiselException: division is illegal on FixedPoint types**
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems to not be implemented yet : https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel3/blob/v3.5.3/core/src/main/scala/chisel3/Bits.scala#L1495

Comment: While using this, it is throwing this:
not found: value throwException
[error] throwException(s"division is illegal on FixedPoint types")
Code:
class FPMul extends Module {

val io = IO(new Bundle {
val a = Input(FixedPoint(4.W, 2.BP))
val b = Input(FixedPoint(4.W, 2.BP))
val p = Output(FixedPoint(8.W, 2.BP))
})
override def do_/(that: FixedPoint)(implicit sourceInfo: SourceInfo, compileOptions: CompileOptions): FixedPoint = throwException(s"division is illegal on FixedPoint types")

io.p := io.a + io.b / 6.0.F(0.BP)

}

Answer (score 0):

It's simply not possible with `FixedPoint`.

As Jack [explained it](https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel3/issues/2660#issuecomment-1208755545), if you want to do division, you will need to implement it yourself.